# Polymer 1.0 Paper-menu-button close on touch outside

Tags: javascript, cordova, drop-down-menu, polymer

I am working on a phonegap app in js and had a problem with polymer. I am trying to have a dropdown like in android using paper-menu-button and it closes when you click on an item now but I can't figure out how to make it close when you touch outside it. Thanks for any help.

```
<paper-menu-button >
    <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Setting</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Profile</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Logout</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
```

Comment: I just had a look at paper-menu-button html file and in there it has (pointer-events: none;) which probably disables mouse and touch events outside. I'm guessing here but take that out or set it to (pointer-events: auto;) and see if it does anything

Comment: I have been looking through paper-menu-button.html and I don't see anything called pointer-events.

Comment: Your'e right, i was looking at this https://github.com/Polymer/paper-menu-button -- thinking is for V.1